# Eclipse RCP make sure new opened view is focused in container

Tags: view, focus, eclipse-rcp

So i have a Folder for views specific ID created

`folderPacket.addPlaceholder(PaketListView.ID+":*");`

when a view in the Folder already exists and a new one is added like this

`showView(viewId, secondaryId, IWorkbenchPage.VIEW_VISIBLE);`

the new view is not in Focus/at front. How can i make sure that the new view is in front and focused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `IWorkbenchPage.VIEW_ACTIVATE` rather than `IWorkbenchPage.VIEW_VISIBLE` on the `showView` call.